# How to flatten words within strings in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

i'd like to know a fast way of flattening strings within a pandas column. I'm wondering if there's a Python function or library that does it quickly instead of iterating through the whole column. For example,

```
DF[COLUMN]
 'Pizza,  Pasta,  Halal'
 'Italian,  Pizza,  Low delivery fee'
 'Coffee,  Breakfast,  Low delivery fee,  Lunch,  Sandwiches'
 'Peri Peri,  Pizza,  Halal'
 'Kebab,  Grill'
 'Lebanese,  Middle Eastern'
 'Fish & Chips,  Kebab,  Halal'
 'Breakfast,  Sandwiches,  Low delivery fee,  Lunch'
 'Fish & Chips,  Street Food'
 'Pizza,  American'
 'Desserts,  Breakfast,  Lunch'
 'Chicken,  Pizza,  Halal'
```

The output would be a single string with all unique values within this column seperated with a comma.

Comment: What do you mean by unique values?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole thing within pandas.

If you split the strings on ', ', then stack the lists, you get all the words in one series. You can then use unique() to get each word only once.
Finally if you want the words in a string separated by ',' then you can join them in the last step.

```
lists_of_words = df['Foodwords'].str.split(', ')
words_in_series = lists_of_words.apply(pd.Series).stack()
unique_words = words_in_series.str.strip("' ").unique()
unique_words_as_string = ", ".join(unique_words)
```